# imcompatible architecture error when importing BigQueryExecuteQueryOperator

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, airflow

I'm trying to import the `BigQueryExecuteQueryOperator` on my local Airflow, installed on the M1 macbook.

```
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.bigquery import BigQueryExecuteQueryOperator
```

The import returns this error:

```
                               | "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/V
                               | ersions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packag
                               | es/pandas/util/_decorators.py", line   
                               | 14, in <module>                        
                               |     from pandas._libs.properties import
                               | cache_readonly  # noqa:F401            
                               |   File                                 
                               | "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/V
                               | ersions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packag
                               | es/pandas/_libs/__init__.py", line 13, 
                               | in <module>                            
                               |     from pandas._libs.interval import  
                               | Interval                               
                               | ImportError:                           
                               | dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.frame
                               | work/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-
                               | packages/pandas/_libs/interval.cpython-
                               | 310-darwin.so, 0x0002): tried:         
                               | '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/V
                               | ersions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packag
                               | es/pandas/_libs/interval.cpython-310-da
                               | rwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an       
                               | incompatible architecture (have        
                               | (x86_64), need (arm64e)))
```

I did some googling and updated my `google-cloud-bigquery` and `grpcio` with `pip`, but the error persists.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Blaze Tama, did the answer below help?

Comment: Hi @Blaze Tama, can you confirm whether your issue is resolved or not?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with Airflow or GCP provider, it's with pandas and nunpy, you should install the version compatible with the ARM64 architecture (apple M1 for ex), here is an example of a code which I used to solve a similar problem one year ago:

```bash
pip3 install Cython
pip3 install --no-binary :all: --no-use-pep517 numpy
pip3 install pandas
pip3 install ib_insync
```

Answer (score 0):

I work in a M1 Macbook.

For me in my local virtual env, I only have to add the `Apache Airflow GCP` package :

requirements.txt file

```
apache-airflow[gcp]==2.3.4
```

In shell terminal :

```bash
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

To manage `Python` versions correctly in my machine I use `PyEnv` : https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv

You can also check the following links that can help with details about environment :

https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki#suggested-build-environment
https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki/Common-build-problems